# Finding multiple documents with one query

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I have a schema like so:

```
schema
{
    owner: <id to other document type>
    created: date
}
```

I have an array of owner's ids: [owner_id_1, owner_id_2, ... owner_id_x]

I want to get a list of documents, with these owners, but limited to just the latest of each. Doing the queries individually:

```
find_one({ owner: owner_id_1 }).sort({ created: -1 }).limit(1)
```

But I don't want to have to fire off x of these, I'd like a way to do it in one query if possible

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [`.aggregate()`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/first/) method allows you do do this, along with matching the documents via the [**`$in`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/in/) operator:

```js
collection.aggregate([
    { "$match": { "owner": { "$in": [owner_id_1, owner_id_2, ... owner_id_x] } },
    { "$group": {
        "_id": "$owner",
        "created": { "$max": "$created" }
    }}
])
```

Gets the maximum ( [**`$max`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/max/) ) "created" value for each "owner" you asked for with the `$in`, which takes an array of values to match the field in the condition.

If you wanted more data than just that one field, the use [**`$sort`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/sort/) before you [**`$group`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/group/):

```js
collection.aggregate([
    { "$match": { "owner": { "$in": [owner_id_1, owner_id_2, ... owner_id_x] } },
    { "$sort": { "owner": 1, "created": -1 } },
    { "$group": {
        "_id": "$owner",
        "created": { "$first": "$created" },
        "docId": { "$first": "$_id" },
        "something": { "$first": "$something" }
    }}
])
```

And the [**`$first`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/first/) takes the first value ( descending was done in sort ) from each grouping boundary.

Comment: So if I have multiple documents with the same parent, this will still just give me a list of documents, each with one of the parents (none with the same parent), and each of those documents is the earliest with that parent?

Comment: @FranciscoRyanTolmaskyI What this is doing ( as you will see when you try ) is exactly the same thing as your individual queries are doing but in a single operation. The `$in` selects all of them at once, and the `$group` just gets a single set of values for each distinct grouping value. Which is the arguments you gave to `$in`.

Comment: Cool, is there a performance penalty for this? For example, if there are 100 documents with owner_id_1, it has to go through the grouping, etc for them. If, hypothetically, the schema had a isFirstDocument boolean, the query would just be { owner: $in: [blah,blah], isFirstDocument: true }, but I have no idea if its a waste to add that field because this stuff you just showed me is plenty fast

Comment: @FranciscoRyanTolmaskyI There is a **lot** more performance penalty in doing 100 separate queries. That said, sometimes parallel operations work well. I suggest you do your own benchmarking and see if you can deal with 100 database connections being made to do this operation. I am just answering the question you asked, which is *"How to do this in a single query"*. This is how you do it. Yes `$in` will work fine as long as you have another selector to identify the document you want. But again, you got two answers for the price of one here, so benchmark and decide what to use.